# Refresh Issue when Serving React build from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

**Problem Description:**

- Developed a React Application which uses Browser Router for Routing.
- Created a build using `yarn build`
- Wrote a simple `NodeJS` server which serves my `react-build/index.html` for the route `'/'`
- Application works great if i don't refresh it.

Now when i refresh the page at `http://website.com/category` it says `Cannot GET /category`

I understand the issue here. As I wrote a single route `/` in my NodeJS server, It can't recognize `website.com/category`. But my react app has all the routing.

**NodeJS Code**

```
server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile (__dirname + '/react-build/index.html') ;
}
```

**React Routing Code**

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path='/cat' component={CategoryPage} />
  <Route path='/quickview/:id' component={QuickView} />
  <Route path='/brand/:brand' component={ProductDetailsPage} />
  <Route path='/product' component={ProductDetailsPage} />
  <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
  <Route path='/myaccount' component={AccountPage} />
</Switch>
```

**Refresh Issue is for all the routes except the root**

I want my application to be able to reload. Hoping to solve this issue with my current implementation. If there is literally no other way than please suggest some alternate solution. Thank you

Comment: @Jaxi this might not be the issue here. As I'm serving my application from Node. And Error i get is also sent from NodeJs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. As i wrote the server route only for `'/'`, My server just understood the Website Root. I changed `'/'` -> `'/*'` and now everything works fine. I hope this answer saves someone's time.

Comment: This strategy will cause error in the other backend API.

Answer (score 0):

If U are serving your react application build from a NodeJS server then rather than using "/" you should treat it as a separate route for UI so u can add a prefix in all your routes i.e "/UI"

If u tried to use "/*" as suggested above your API will start crashing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just get the raw JSON data when I refresh the page: for instance

```
server.get("/states", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    "states": [
      "Adamawa", "Lagos", ...
  ]
 }) ;
}
```

If I refresh the page that has this route, the server will crash, the ui won't show, I'll only get the raw JSON like so

Comment: What would you advise? #node.js & #react.js developers

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33525719)